# How to refresh a jquery datatable

Tags: php, jquery, datatable

I want to refresh my jquery datatable. I've tried the code below, but it doesn't work. Any ideas please? :)

```
function rafraichir(){
   $('#rafraichir').click( function () {
        var nHidden = datatable.fnGetHiddenNodes();
        alert( nHidden.length +' nodes were returned');
   } );
};
```

**Update:**

```
function rafraichir(){
    $('#datatables').dataTable().fnClearTable();
    $('#datatables').dataTable().fnDraw();
    $('#datatables').dataTable().fnAddData();   
};
```

I tried this code , the fnClearTable does work  but the other functions return  this erreur : 
 $('#datatables').dataTable().fnDraw();
undefined
    $('#datatables').dataTable().fnAddData();
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of unde

Comment: Not enough code here to help. What is `datatable`? What does the `fnGetHiddenNodes()` function do? What result are you getting? What result do you expect?

Comment: Your code should work, I see nothing syntactically wrong with it. Does `var nHidden` contain the expected data after calling `fnGetHiddenNodes()`?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the datatables api located [HERE](http://datatables.net/api)

You can force a redraw of the table doing something like this.

```
$(document).ready(
{
    $('#rafraichir').click( function () 
    {
        $('#tableSelector').dataTable().fnDraw();
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried this code and also I've tried the function  fnReload , but it doesn't work !! I'don't know  but  , is that because of the datatable version ?????

Comment: This doesn't work but should I change tha databla version ???